# InvalidDocumentError when using Mapfield and DynamicEmbeddedDocument together

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine, graphene-python

I have a mongo schema data:

```
{
"key_1":{"internal_k1":"internal_v1","internal_k2":"internal_v2"},
"key_2":{"internal_k3":"internal_v3","internal_k4":"internal_v4"},
}
```

and a mongoengine model:

```py
class ONE(DynamicEmbeddedDocument):
   internal_k1 = StringField()
   internal_k2 = StringField()

class TWO(DynamicEmbeddedDocument):
   internal_k3 = StringField()
   internal_k4 = StringField()

class Test(Document):
   key_1 = MapField(EmbeddedDocumentField(ONE))
   key_2 = MapField(EmbeddedDocumentField(TWO))
```

i have included the DynamicEmbeddedDocument because the key_1 and key_2 can have extra dynamic fields.

I am inserting the data manually:
while loading the data using model it throws error as follows

mongoengine.errors.InvalidDocumentError: Invalid data to create a `Test` instance.

i am using mongoengine as a python library.

I need a correct model to support this data structure.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see, you don't need to wrap the EmbeddedDocumentField in MapField's, try the following:

```
class ONE(DynamicEmbeddedDocument):
   internal_k1 = StringField()
   internal_k2 = StringField()

class TWO(DynamicEmbeddedDocument):
   internal_k3 = StringField()
   internal_k4 = StringField()

class Test(Document):
   key_1 = EmbeddedDocumentField(ONE)
   key_2 = EmbeddedDocumentField(TWO)
```